# GraphQL Query to Array List using React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am currently working on a gatsby website and am mostly using react components doing so. The way our jobs posting page currently works is that it fetches a list of jobs from an array that stores the information for each position and maps them out with proper stylization.

**positions.js (section)**

```
const Positions = () => (
  <StyledPositions>
    <GlobalContainer>
      {PositionList.map((position, index) => (
        <StyledPosition key={index}>
          <StyledPositionName>
            <Link to={position.link} activeClassName="active">
              {position.name}
            </Link>
          </StyledPositionName>
        </StyledPosition>
      ))}
    </GlobalContainer>
  </StyledPositions>
);

export default Positions;
```

PositionList is the array and it looks like this.

**positionslist.js**

```
const Positionlist = [
  {
    name: "Senior Software Engineer- Infrastructure",
    link: "/careers/open_positions/sr_cloud_eng",
  },
  {
    name: "System Software Engineer",
    link: "/careers/open_positions/system_soft_eng",
  },
  {
    name: "Software Engineer (Database Development)",
    link: "/careers/open_positions/soft_eng_database",
  },
];

export default Positionlist;
```

What I'm trying to do is to populate the job posting site from a GraphQL query from an external job posting management site. I am able to fetch the information fine, but I'd like to somehow turn the information into an array like positionslist.js so that positions.js can simply map the information the same way. The query looks like this

```
query MyQuery {
  allLever {
    edges {
      node {
        text
        categories {
          commitment
          location
          team
        }
        applyUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you're *'able to fetch the information fine'* ... then you know where is an array in this structure ... read docs/follow tutorials - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/creating-a-source-plugin/#querying-and-sourcing-data-from-a-remote-location

Answer (score 0):

All GraphQL queries store their result inside `props.data` as you can see in [Gatsby's tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/). At this point, you only need to enter to the nested structure like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const Positions = ({data}) => {
  let PositionList = data.edges;
  
  return <StyledPositions>
    <GlobalContainer>
      {PositionList.map(({node: position}) => (
        <StyledPosition key={position.name}>
          <StyledPositionName>
            <Link to={position.link} activeClassName="active">
              {position.name}
            </Link>
          </StyledPositionName>
        </StyledPosition>
      ))}
    </GlobalContainer>
  </StyledPositions>
}
export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
  allLever {
    edges {
      node {
        name: text
        categories {
          commitment
          location
          team
        }
        link: applyUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
`
export default Positions
```

*Note: it's better to avoid using `index` as `key` so you can use another field*

Keep in mind that you barely need to change your previous structure (because of some destructuring + aliasing) but, what's important is that page queries, only work in pages (hence the name) so I'm assuming that `Positions` is a separate page. Otherwise, you will need to pass down the `props` from the page component.

Because of the aliasing, `applyUrl` will be aliased as `link` and `text` to `name`, so your previous structure will work exactly in the same way.